# Can I still install Play 2.4 at the moment?

Tags: playframework

In the official tutorial https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Installing, it asks me to install something called TypeSafe Activator which I cannot find a download link at anywhere. Is there any other way to install it or do I have to try a later version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news - the Activator is gone:

"We’re changing how developers get started with Lightbend technologies, which unfortunately means that future releases of Play, Akka and Scala will no longer include Activator support, and Lightbend’s Activator server will be decommissioned by the end of 2017."

https://www.lightbend.com/blog/introducing-a-new-way-to-get-started-with-lightbend-technologies-and-saying-goodbye-to-activator

You can use the sbt build tool.